# Why does this return Nil in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I ran this command:

```
user1 = User.create(:email => 'test12@abc.com', :password => 'test12123', :username => 'test12', :first_name => 'Test', :last_name => 'User', :plan_id => '4')
```

and got this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `trial_duration' for nil:NilClass
```

This is my User model:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110412170916
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                   :integer         not null, primary key
#  email                :string(255)
#  encrypted_password   :string(128)
#  password_salt        :string(255)
#  reset_password_token :string(255)
#  remember_token       :string(255)
#  remember_created_at  :datetime
#  sign_in_count        :integer
#  current_sign_in_at   :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at      :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip   :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip      :string(255)
#  username             :string(255)
#  first_name           :string(255)
#  last_name            :string(255)
#  created_at           :datetime
#  updated_at           :datetime
#  invitation_token     :string(60)
#  invitation_sent_at   :datetime
#  plan_id              :integer
#  current_state        :string(255)
#  confirmation_token   :string(255)
#  confirmed_at         :datetime
#  confirmation_sent_at :datetime
#  space_used           :integer         default(0), not null
#  failed_attempts      :integer         default(0)
#  unlock_token         :string(255)
#  locked_at            :datetime
#  trial_end_date       :date
#  active_subscription  :boolean
#

belongs_to :plan

before_create :set_trial_end

def set_trial_end
     plan = self.plan
     end_of_trial = self.created_at + plan.trial_duration.days
     self.trial_end_date = end_of_trial
end
```

This is my Plan model:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110412101615
#
# Table name: plans
#
#  id                  :integer         not null, primary key
#  name                :string(255)
#  storage             :float
#  num_of_projects     :integer
#  num_of_clients      :integer
#  cached_slug         :string(255)
#  created_at          :datetime
#  updated_at          :datetime
#  amount              :integer
#  trial_duration      :integer
#  trial_duration_unit :string(255)
#  currency            :string(255)
#  billing_cycle       :integer
#  billing_cycle_unit  :string(255)
#

class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many  :users
    has_many    :subscriptions
    has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true

end
```

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure :plan_id is in your attr_accessible list on your User model, or is NOT on your attr_protected list. This will prevent plan_id from being assigned in that User.create statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rather:

```
plan = Plan.find(4)
user1 = User.create(:email => 'test12@abc.com', :password => 'test12123', :username => 'test12', :first_name => 'Test', :last_name => 'User', :plan => plan)
```

It is failing due to not finding the associated "plan" object.

Comment: Simon, no luck :( `ruby-1.9.2-p0 > plan
 => #<Plan id: 4, name: "Huey", storage: 30.0, num_of_projects: 99999, num_of_clients: 99999, cached_slug: "huey", created_at: "2011-01-31 09:48:59", updated_at: "2011-04-13 23:56:27", amount: 399, trial_duration: 7, trial_duration_unit: "days", currency: "USD", billing_cycle: 28, billing_cycle_unit: "days"> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > user1 = User.create(:email => 'test12@abc.com', :password => 'test12123', :username => 'test12', :first_name => 'Test', :last_name => 'User', :plan => plan)
NoMethodError: undefined method 'trial_duration' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the association explicitly? Similar to what Simon said, but like:

```
plan = Plan.find(4)
user = [code to create the user, but without the "plan" or "plan_id" attribute]
user.plan = plan
user.save
```

Or, in your code, try doing `:plan_id => 4` instead of `'4'`.

Comment: This works...but ONLY if I comment out the  `before_create :set_trial_end`. If I don't, it doesn't allow me to save.

Answer (score 1):

in `before_create :set_trial_end` the plan has not been fetched yet.

I think you would need to manually fetch plan in `def set_trial_end`

```
def set_trial_end
  plan = Plan.find(plan_id)
  end_of_trial = self.created_at + plan.trial_duration.days
  self.trial_end_date = end_of_trial
end
```

You will probably need a virtual attribute called plan_id that gets set on the create.

Comment: I tried this, but I get this: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Plan without an ID`

Comment: If I change this to be `plan = Plan.find(4)` then this works wonderfully. But with `plan_id`. No such luck.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you have to add trial_duration to your attr_accessible.

Try this:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many  :users
has_many    :subscriptions
has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true
attr_accessible :trial_duration
end
```

This is due the fact rails auto-protect from mass assignments.

Comment: This looks like an interesting one, but I still got this error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Plan without an ID`